# Full base url appended after base url when reaching page

Tags: magento2, url, base-url

For a demo environment, I had to upload my Magento project to a server, without a domain name. My Magento base URL is http://62.221.209.128/plesk-site-preview/rodrigootazu.com/62.221.209.128/, but as you can see when I reach it the full URL is appended behind it.

What is causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can check is the website's base URL from the database. To do that, log in to the database and open the table **`core_config_data`**.

Find all the entries like **`web/unsecure/base_url`** and **`web/secure/base_url`** and update these with your real base URL (like http://62.221.209.128/plesk-site-preview/rodrigootazu.com/62.221.209.128/).

Note the slash (/) at the last of the URL.

Remove **`var/cache`**, **`var/page_cache`**, **`var/view_processed`**, **`pub/static/frontend`** and **`generated`** folders under the document root.

Check the website again. If it does not help, check whether the server has **`mod_rewrite`** enabled or not. If it is not enabled, first enable it.

If still, there is no change, check for any **`rewrite rules`** in the **`.htaccess`** file in the document root.

I hope it should help.